# How to convert sympy.core.numbers.Float types to just native python float type, or directly plot them

Tags: python, sympy

Do you know how I can copy my code without losing indentation format from jupyter notebook. I tried downloading different formats and I can not make a picture copy of output. The output of the code is as follows:
T(K)= 399
-0.0937999028234458 - 4.15858122699766e-24*I <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> b nsolve
T(K)= 449
0.00365302829594929 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 499
0.0688176963782414 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 549
0.137782216780566 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 599
0.202639297806409 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 649
0.264652306977205 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 699
0.327062973503106 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 749
0.394405805295084 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 799
0.474908685390235 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 849
0.596849248832071 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 899
0.710661123937097 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
T(K)= 949
0.797426959030511 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve

I need following plot lines to plot a and b. It does not work because sympy type problem

```
#plt.scatter(a,t)


#plt.scatter(b,t)
```

How can I convert a and b to normal float numbers or complex numbers or delete complex but keep only float numbers in  a different list? It works if the data was converted to a list by hand copy paste from output but not directly within the  code.
I actually need to delete complex roots from the list "a". The problem is the type of
"class 'sympy.core.add.Add" and <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>.

thanks for any suggestions..

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib
import scipy as sp
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
from sympy import symbols,solve,Eq
x,y=symbols('x y')
gfyx=symbols('x y')
gfyx=symbols('x y')
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections.abc import Iterable
import gc
def flatten(lis):
     for item in lis:
         if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str):
             for x in flatten(item):
                 yield x
         else:        
             yield item
L=[];T1=[];T2=[];T3=[];T4=[];AB2=[];AB1=[];AB3=[];AB4=[];HCP=[];BCC=[]
CC=[];VV=[];j=[];tt=[];KK=[];TK=[];K=[];T=[];S=[];DGMIX=[];DGMIXX=[];DGMIXY=[];L0L=[];L1L=[];L2L=[]
L0BCC=[];L1BCC=[];L2BCC=[];MGLQ=[];LILQ=[];G0MG=[];G0LI=[];LIQUID=[];BCC=[]
L0HCP=[];L1HCP=[];L2HCP=[];CC=[];VV=[];j=[];tt=[];KK=[];TK=[];K=[];T=[];S=[];xx=[];a=[];b=[]

x,y=symbols('x y')
gfyx=symbols('x y')
e1=symbols('x y')
e2=symbols('x y')
e3=symbols('x y')
e4=symbols('x y')
z=symbols('x y')
k=symbols('x y')
gfyx=symbols('x y')                               
t=399
while t<995:
    #x = np.linspace(0.01,0.99,10)
    print("T(K)=",t)
if t>298.15:
    G0MG=3100-2.1*t;    G0LI=-154+2*t;    L0L=-14935+10.371*t;    L1L=-1789+1.143*t;    
L2L=6633-6.6915*t
        L0BCC=8.49*t-18335;    L1BCC=3481;    L2BCC=2658- 
0.114*t;L0HCP=-6856;L1HCP=4000;L2HCP=4000
    if 298.15<=t<923:
        MGLQ=8202.243-8.83693*t-8.0176*10**-20*t**7
        #print("MGLQ 923 k ",MGLQ)
    if 923<=t<2000:
        MGLQ=8690.316-(9.392159*t)-1.0382*10**28*t**-9
        #print("MGLQ 923 k ",MGLQ)
# 
if 298.15<=t<453.69:
    LILQ=2958.992-6.507019*t-1.7244*10**-18*t**7    
    #print("LILQ 453 K ",LILQ)
# 
if 453.69<=t<2000:
    LILQ=3031.767-6.675446*t-2.5929*10**24*t**-9
    #print("LILQ 453 K ",LILQ)
DGMIXX=8.314*t*(((1-x)*log(1-x))+(x*log(x)))
DGMIXY=8.314*t*(((1-y)*log(1-y))+(y*log(y)))
LIQUID=x*MGLQ+(1-x)*LILQ+(DGMIXX)+(x*(1-x))*((L0L+L1L*(1-2*x)+(L2L*((1-2*x)**2))))
BCC=y*G0MG+(DGMIXY)+(y*(1-y)*((L0BCC+L1BCC*(1-2*y)+(L2BCC*((1-2*y)**2)))))
#HCP=(1-x)*G0LI+(DGMIX)+(x*(1-x)*((L0HCP+L1HCP*(1-2*x)+(L2HCP*((1-2*x)**2)))))
#print("LILQ=",LILQ,"MGLQ=",MGLQ)
#print("LIQ=",LIQUID)
#print("BCC=",BCC)
#f=x**2+2*x
#g=y**2-4*y
z = LIQUID
k = BCC
#print("f=",f)
#print("g=",g)
#df = f.diff(x)
#dg = g.diff(y)
dz = z.diff(x)
dk = k.diff(y)
#print("df=",df)
#print("dg=",dg)
#e1 = Eq((df)*(y-x)-g+f,0) 
#e2 = Eq((dg)*(y-x)-g+f,0)
#e1 = Eq(df-dg,0)
e3 = (dz-dk)
e4 = (dk)*(y-x)-k+z
a,b=nsolve([(e3), (e4)], [x, y], [0.1, 0.2],verify=False)
print(a,type(a),"b nsolve")
#plt.scatter(a,t)
#plt.scatter(b,t)
t=t+50
```

###################################################### below is edited code

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib
import scipy as sp
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
from sympy import symbols,solve,Eq
x,y=symbols('x y')
gfyx=symbols('x y')
gfyx=symbols('x y')
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections.abc import Iterable
import gc
def flatten(lis):
     for item in lis:
         if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str):
             for x in flatten(item):
                 yield x
         else:        
             yield item
L=[];T1=[];T2=[];T3=[];T4=[];AB2=[];AB1=[];AB3=[];AB4=[];HCP=[];BCC=[]
CC=[];VV=[];j=[];tt=[];KK=[];TK=[];K=[];T=[];S=[];DGMIX=[];DGMIXX=[];DGMIXY=[];L0L=[];L1L=[];L2L=[]
L0BCC=[];L1BCC=[];L2BCC=[];MGLQ=[];LILQ=[];G0MG=[];G0LI=[];LIQUID=[];BCC=[]
L0HCP=[];L1HCP=[];L2HCP=[];CC=[];VV=[];j=[];tt=[];KK=[];TK=[];K=[];T=[];S=[];xx=[];a=[];b=[]

x,y=symbols('x y')
gfyx=symbols('x y')
e1=symbols('x y')
e2=symbols('x y')
e3=symbols('x y')
e4=symbols('x y')
z=symbols('x y')
k=symbols('x y')
gfyx=symbols('x y')                               
t=399
while t<995:
    #x = np.linspace(0.01,0.99,10)
    print("T(K)=",t)
    if t>298.15:
        G0MG=3100-2.1*t;    G0LI=-154+2*t;    L0L=-14935+10.371*t;    L1L=-1789+1.143*t;    
        L2L=6633-6.6915*t
        L0BCC=8.49*t-18335;    L1BCC=3481;    L2BCC=2658- 0.114*t;L0HCP=-6856;L1HCP=4000;L2HCP=4000
    if 298.15<=t<923:
        MGLQ=8202.243-8.83693*t-8.0176*10**-20*t**7
        #print("MGLQ 923 k ",MGLQ)
    if 923<=t<2000:
        MGLQ=8690.316-(9.392159*t)-1.0382*10**28*t**-9
        #print("MGLQ 923 k ",MGLQ)
# 
    if 298.15<=t<453.69:
        LILQ=2958.992-6.507019*t-1.7244*10**-18*t**7    
        #print("LILQ 453 K ",LILQ)
# 
    if 453.69<=t<2000:
        LILQ=3031.767-6.675446*t-2.5929*10**24*t**-9
        #print("LILQ 453 K ",LILQ)
    DGMIXX=8.314*t*(((1-x)*log(1-x))+(x*log(x)))
    DGMIXY=8.314*t*(((1-y)*log(1-y))+(y*log(y)))
    LIQUID=x*MGLQ+(1-x)*LILQ+(DGMIXX)+(x*(1-x))*((L0L+L1L*(1-2*x)+(L2L*((1-2*x)**2))))
    BCC=y*G0MG+(DGMIXY)+(y*(1-y)*((L0BCC+L1BCC*(1-2*y)+(L2BCC*((1-2*y)**2)))))
    #HCP=(1-x)*G0LI+(DGMIX)+(x*(1-x)*((L0HCP+L1HCP*(1-2*x)+(L2HCP*((1-2*x)**2)))))
    #print("LILQ=",LILQ,"MGLQ=",MGLQ)
    #print("LIQ=",LIQUID)
    #print("BCC=",BCC)
    #f=x**2+2*x
    #g=y**2-4*y
    z = LIQUID
    k = BCC
    #print("f=",f)
    #print("g=",g)
    #df = f.diff(x)
    #dg = g.diff(y)
    dz = z.diff(x)
    dk = k.diff(y)
    #print("df=",df)
    #print("dg=",dg)
    #e1 = Eq((df)*(y-x)-g+f,0) 
    #e2 = Eq((dg)*(y-x)-g+f,0)
    #e1 = Eq(df-dg,0)
    e3 = (dz-dk)
    e4 = (dk)*(y-x)-k+z
    a,b=nsolve([(e3), (e4)], [x, y], [0.1, 0.2],verify=False)
    print(a,type(a),"b nsolve")
    if type(a)=="sympy.core.numbers.Float":
        a=float(a)
        print("inside corefloat")
    elif type(a)=="sympy.core.add.Add":
        a=complex(a)
    
    print(type(a))
    #plt.scatter(a,t)
    #plt.scatter(b,t)
    t=t+50

the following is the output: 
T(K)= 399
-0.0937999028234458 - 4.15858122699766e-24*I <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
T(K)= 449
0.00365302829594929 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 499
0.0688176963782414 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 549
0.137782216780566 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 599
0.202639297806409 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 649
0.264652306977205 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 699
0.327062973503106 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 749
0.394405805295084 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 799
0.474908685390235 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 849
0.596849248832071 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 899
0.710661123937097 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
T(K)= 949
0.797426959030511 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'> b nsolve
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
```

Comment: Get rid of all those `scipy` imports.  Unless you really know how to integrate `sympy` and `scipy`, don't try it.  `lambdify` is one of the few safe ways of using `sympy` and `numpy` together.  `sympy` also has its plotting tools.

Comment: There's too much code, and not enough full error messages (with traceback).  If you want help, clearly isolate the problem.

Comment: If the symbolic numbers contain expressions such as `sqrt`, you could use `expression.evalf()` to get them numeric.  As noted by hpaulj, `math`, `scipy`, `numpy` etc. don't mix well with sympy.  You really should separate out the sympy part of your code.

Comment: Your code is not runnable.  Even when I make the obvious fixes, indents are wrong and it gets stuck in the `while` loop.

Comment: Sorry for indent problem. I tried everything but when I copy/paste the code some indentations gets mixed up. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with numbers in SymPy they might be a Number (Integer, Rational, Float) or number (number constant like pi or expression with functions or radicals with numeric args). You can convert both types to floats using Python's `float` function:

```
>>> from sympy import pi, sqrt, S
>>> float(S(1/2))  # a Float
0.5
>>> float(pi - sqrt(2))  # an Add
1.7273790912166982
```

If the numbers have imaginary parts you might want to use Python's `complex` and then take the real or imaginary part as desired:

```
>>> complex(1+2*I)
(1+2j)
>>> _.real, _.imag
(1.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: I tried using type comparisons but it wont work.  the problem is "T(K)= 399 -0.0937999028234458 - 4.15858122699766e-24*I <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>" and "T(K)= 449 0.00365302829594929 <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'" have different types and I can not use boolean to compare them... I mean with if ...

Comment: I used this                         a,b=nsolve([(e3), (e4)], [x, y], [0.1, 0.2],verify=False)
    print(a,type(a),"b nsolve")
    if type(a)=="sympy.core.numbers.Float":
        a=float(a)
        print("inside corefloat")
    elif type(a)=="sympy.core.add.Add":
        a=complex(a)

Comment: Did you try `a,b=[complex(i).real for i in nsolve([(e3), (e4)], [x, y], [0.1, 0.2],verify=False)]`? This assumes you have only real answers with, perhaps, a nuisance imaginary part.

Comment: Thanks, it seems working  with complex class "sympy.core.add.Add"  problem. However, it gives the wrong answer for complex root as real number. I need to remove any complex roots or I dont want the results other than positive values. I also realized that this nsolve gives different solutions for different runs for some values? Is that possible? Do you know how to give results only between 0 and 1. like a domain for nsolve. Because a and b are between 0 and 1 and they are supposed to be all positive... Thanks

Comment: To get roots between 0 and 1 from nsolve you would have to find brackets for the root and use the bisection solver, e.g. `nsolve(x**2-.5, (0,2), solver='bisect') -> .707...`